How to add ":" to xls filename after download using angular - ":" gets replaced by "_"
I have the angular code below to download xls file from API response, I am trying to change the file name to filenameDD_HH:MM . For some reason, the ":" is replaced with "" after download. Tried regex to replace ":" with "" , doesnt work as well.
downloadFile() {
this.servcie.downloadReport().subscribe({
next:(response)=>{
const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href=url;
var today = new Date();
let hours = today.getHours() + ":";
let minuted = today.getMinutes() + ":";
anchor.download = "myfile_" + hours + minutes + ".xls";
anchor.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
})

}


there are certain forbidden characters/phrases for filenames.  ":" is one of them.

@browsermator thank you, Is there anyway I can add : to file name?

that might depend on the OS.  It doesn't seem very secure though.  (There are reasons for those restrictions...)

in addition to certain characters, you should also avoid "CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9"  As Windows treats those as calls to serial ports/devices.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file  I think Linux/Unix has less restrictions.  There is also a max character limit, though that's pretty large these days.
